# storing the output of awk command into a variable

Tags: shell, sh

I want to store the output of command into var1 and var2 I tried with the below code.in 1.text and 2.text I have below contents

```
             1.text
             <assertive
             <acidify
             <something
             <code-bat

             2.text
             <assertive
             <acidify
             >fish
             >Fruehauf

            var1 = `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' 1.text 2.text`
            var2 = `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' 2.text 1.text`
            echo $var1;
            echo "================================================";
            echo $var2;
```

Comment: var1 = `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' 1.txt 2.txt`
var2 = `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' 2.txt 1.txt`
echo $var1;
echo "================================================";
echo $var2;

Comment: above is the code is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var=$(command)
```

and read a shell tutorial.